# I am having MongoDB Cast Error anyone know what this means?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, mongoose

I am having this unknown error but in my interface and Schema I am not defining any field with the property of ObjectId
and this is probably the first ever error of its kind to appear here so I really hope this gets fixed

```
GET /auth/discord/redirect?code=MsYzdlnjVC6upRhp37LmK5HbFP9IPW 302 7085.898 ms - 64
    /Discord Authentication/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schema/objectId.js:250
    throw new CastError('ObjectId', value, this.path, error, this);
          ^
   CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{
     id: {
      discordId: '713145789463134269',
      globalName: 'URIZEN',
        _id: new ObjectId("65536ab9bec76a177731bb99"),
       __v: 0
      }
    }" (type Object) at path "_id" for model "User"
```

Comment: Can you share your User model and related function that you get the error?

Comment: My best guesses: Either you're doing a `new ObjectId(<not a valid ObjectId string>)"` or you have a document in your database where `_id` is not an ObjectId, and you tell mongoose that it should be ObjectId so mongoose will try to convert this broken data to an ObjectId and raise an error.

Comment: "*and this is probably the first ever error of it's kind to appear here*" sadly not. Mongoose is trying to cast a value to an `ObjectId` for you. When a document is created (unless specified otherwise) it receives an `_id` field with a type of `Objectid`. Whatever operation you are trying to do (update/create etc) you are providing a value that cannot be cast to `ObjectId`. As @OnurDoğan says, post the code where you perform the function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.